# RXJS, Calculate how long an observable takes to complete

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

I am working on my application to increase the speed
Actually, I have two observables. I want to know how long each of them take to complete, and which of them is faster. What is the best way to gain this.

Answer (score 0):

Depends a little bit how you can access the observables. But assuming you have the abservable like this:

```
const first$ = Observable.of('sth')
const second$ = Observable.of('sthElse')
```

you can wrap them

```
export const logDuration(sourceObservable$) {
  const start = moment()
  return Observable.of(start).pipe(
    tap(start => console.log('start: ', start)),
    switchMap(() => sourceObservable$),
    tap(() => {
      const finished = moment();
      const duration = finished.duration(start);
      console.log('finished:', finished);
      console.log('duration:', duration);
    }

}
```